# Scala Lift - Sitemap menu builder custom css classes

Tags: css, scala, lift

I've got the following site map defined in Boot.scala:

```
SiteMap(

    Menu(S ? "Home") / "index",
    Menu(S ? "About") / "about",
    Menu(S ? "Work") / "work",
    Menu(S ? "Contact") / "contact"

)
```

With the following markup:

```
<lift:Menu.builder />
```

What I'm trying to do is in someway identify the menu items to style each seperatly.

Is there a way to define a unique class for each sitemap entry or perhaps add the name of the menu item to the title attribute which I could also use to style them?

So the markup is rendered like this:

```
<a href="/about" title="about">About</a>
```

Or

```
<a href="/about" class="about">About</a>
```

Thanks in advance, any help much appreciated :)

**UPDATE**

Until a more robust way of doing this is found, I've opted to style each link in the menu via simple attribute reference, e.g:

```
a[href="/about"] { color:#000; }
```

Answer (score 1):

I would take a look at the `Menu.item` section here: http://exploring.liftweb.net/master/index-7.html#toc-Subsection-7.2.3

That should allow you to add specific classes to particular items of the `SiteMap`, which sounds like exactly what you want to do.

Comment: Thanks for the link, useful but not quite what I'm after. I've gone the route of extending the stock Menu.builder to suite my needs.

Answer (score 0):

If your site menu is not really simple, you can consider to hard-code your menu inside the HTML code. Obviously, Lift's simple menu can't handle *everything*.

You can also create menu groups and render these groups separately.